# What's the reason why this sequence of function doesn't converge uniformly to $f$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Consider $f_n = \sqrt[n]{x}$ on $[0,1]$

So it converges to the step function $f = 0$ if $x = 0$ and $f=1$ otherwise

I could see why it doesn't converge if i draw an epsilon rectangle over one part since for each $n$, $f_n$ lies completely outside of the function.

If I draw an epsilon rectangle over the whole $f$, I don't see why this isn't uniform convergence

EDIT: I got this from Spivak, so keep it at that level please...

**Added question**: if $f_n\nrightarrow f$ for some $x \in \mathbb{R}$, can I conclude that it is not uniformly convergent over $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: What do you know about the limit of a uniformly convergent sequence of continuous functions?

Comment: Oh then the limit $f$ must also be continuous, if the set is closed and bounded right? But in my notebook, I wrote down that pointwise convergence does not imply regular convergence.

Comment: @sizz: You are right to say that pointwise convergence does not imply uniform convergence. The problem that you have described proves exactly this fact. However, uniform convergence implies pointwise convergence, as I have shown below.

Comment: What about pointwise *divergence*? Does that imply $f_n$ cannot uniformly converge?

Comment: @Sizz: I also answered this question below. You see, uniform convergence implies pointwise convergence. If you have pointwise *divergence*, then you cannot have uniform convergence, otherwise you would have pointwise convergence --- a contradiction. :)

Comment: @Sizz: Therefore, if $ (f_{n})_{n \in \mathbb{N}} $ fails to converge pointwise to $ f $, i.e., there exists an $ x \in [0,1] $ such that $ {f_{n}}(x) \nrightarrow f(x) $, then $ (f_{n})_{n \in \mathbb{N}} $ *fails* to converge uniformly to $ f $.

Comment: For this problem, I (or rather, we) showed that $ (f_{n})_{n \in \mathbb{N}} $ already converges pointwise to a discontinuous function. As such, it cannot converge pointwise to a continuous function because pointwise limits are unique.

Comment: I am just getting confused because I tried to compare this definition with the regular sequence (of numbers) definition and its uniqueness like you suggested. In here $f$ can be broken into piecewise and I am having problems wrapping my head that each of these pieceiwse values is considered as "one limit"

Comment: @sizz: You can think of the pointwise limit of a sequence of functions as the *collection* of limits of such regular sequences. For each $ x \in [0,1] $, you have a regular sequence $ ({f_{n}}(x))_{n \in \mathbb{N}} $ of numbers, right? If you plug $ x $ into the pointwise limit $ f $, the output $ f(x) $ is simply the value of the limit of the regular sequence $ \displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty} {f_{n}}(x) $.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I like @hardmath's approach in the comments above. But here is an approach using the definition of uniform convergence.

Assume $\{f_n\}$ converges uniformly to $f$. Pick $\varepsilon < 1/2$. We can find an $N$ for which $\forall x \in [0, 1] : |f_N(x) - f(x)| < \varepsilon$. Clearly, $f_N(1) = 1$ and $f_N(0) = 0$. Since $f_N$ is continuous, we can find $x \in (0, 1)$ for which $f_N(x) = 1/2$ (by the [intermediate value theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intermediate_value_theorem)). This means that $|f_N(x) - 1| = 1/2 > \varepsilon$. This is a contradiction and $\{f_n\}$ doesn't converge uniformly to $f$.

---

Here is a plot of $f_{10}(x) = \sqrt[10]{x}$:

[image: plot]

Since $f_n$ is continuous, there will always be values of $x > 0$ for which $f_n(x)$ is too far away from $1$. Uniform convergence requires that after a certain $N$, $f_n(x)$ must be within a small distance $\varepsilon$ from $f(x)$ for all $x$ . This fails for the sequence we have.

Comment: Why is $|f_N(x) - 1| = 1/2$?

Comment: @sizz Because we picked $x$ so that $f_N(x) = 1/2$.

Comment: Would it be too much to ask to draw me a picture? I am have trouble visualing $|f_N(x) - f(x)| < \epsilon$ part

Comment: @sizz I edited my question with a plot and more text to help you visualize it.

Answer (score 5):

We will first prove two results.

> **Theorem 1** Let $ (f_{n})_{n \in \mathbb{N}} $ be a sequence of continuous functions on $ [0,1] $ that converges uniformly to some function $ f $ on $ [0,1] $. Then $ f $ must be continuous on $ [0,1] $.

*Proof*: Let $ \epsilon > 0 $. Then there exists an $ N \in \mathbb{N} $ such that for all integers $ n \geq N $, we have
$$
\forall x \in [0,1]: \quad |{f_{n}}(x) - f(x)| < \frac{\epsilon}{3}.
$$
To prove that $ f $ is continuous, pick an arbitrary $ x_{0} \in [0,1] $. As $ f_{N} $ is continuous by assumption, there exists a $ \delta > 0 $ such that $ |{f_{N}}(x_{0}) - {f_{N}}(x)| < \dfrac{\epsilon}{3} $ for all $ x \in (x_{0} - \delta,x_{0} + \delta) \cap [0,1] $. Hence, by the Triangle Inequality, we see that for all $ x \in (x_{0} - \delta,x_{0} + \delta) \cap [0,1] $, the following relations hold:
\begin{align}
      |f(x_{0}) - f(x)|
&=    |[f(x_{0}) - {f_{N}}(x_{0})] + [{f_{N}}(x_{0}) - {f_{N}}(x)] + [{f_{N}}(x) - f(x)]| \\
&\leq |f(x_{0}) - {f_{N}}(x_{0})| + |{f_{N}}(x_{0}) - {f_{N}}(x)| + |{f_{N}}(x) - f(x)| \\
&<    \frac{\epsilon}{3} + \frac{\epsilon}{3} + \frac{\epsilon}{3} \\
&=    \epsilon.
\end{align}
As $ x_{0} $ and $ \epsilon $ are arbitrary, we conclude that $ f $ is indeed continuous on $ [0,1] $. $ \quad \spadesuit $

> **Theorem 2** Let $ (f_{n})_{n \in \mathbb{N}} $ be a sequence of (not-necessarily-continuous) functions on $ [0,1] $ that converges uniformly to some function $ f $ on $ [0,1] $. Then $ (f_{n})_{n \in \mathbb{N}} $ converges *pointwise* to $ f $.

*Proof*: This follows directly from the definition of uniform convergence. For any $ \epsilon > 0 $, there exists an $ N \in \mathbb{N} $ such that for all integers $ n \geq N $, we have
$$
\forall x \in [0,1]: \quad |{f_{n}}(x) - f(x)| < \epsilon.
$$
Therefore, for all $ x \in [0,1] $, we get $ \displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty} {f_{n}}(x) = f(x) $. $ \quad \spadesuit $

This corollary is in response to the OP's latest question.

> **Corollary** Let $ (f_{n})_{n \in \mathbb{N}} $ be a sequence of (not-necessarily-continuous) functions on $ [0,1] $ and $ f $ a function on $ [0,1] $ also. If $ {f_{n}}(x) \nrightarrow f(x) $ for some $ x \in [0,1] $, then $ (f_{n})_{n \in \mathbb{N}} $ *does not* converge uniformly to $ f $.

*Proof*: By Theorem 2, uniform convergence implies pointwise convergence; if pointwise convergence fails, then uniform convergence fails. $ \quad \spadesuit $

---

Assume now, for the sake of contradiction, that the sequence $ (f_{n})_{n \in \mathbb{N}} := (\sqrt[n]{\bullet})_{n \in \mathbb{N}} $ of continuous functions on $ [0,1] $ converges uniformly to some function $ f $ on $ [0,1] $. By Theorem 1, $ f $ is continuous on $ [0,1] $. By Theorem 2, $ f $ can be computed as the pointwise limit of $ (f_{n})_{n \in \mathbb{N}} $. Hence,
\begin{equation}
f(x) = \left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
0 & \text{if $ x = 0 $}; \\
1 & \text{if $ x \in (0,1] $}.
\end{array} \right.
\end{equation}
However, $ f $ is clearly not continuous at $ 0 $, thus contradicting Theorem 1.

**Conclusion:** $ (f_{n})_{n \in \mathbb{N}} $ *does not* converge uniformly to any function on $ [0,1] $. However, it does converge pointwise to the piecewise-defined function $ f $ described above.

The main point here is that uniform convergence and pointwise convergence are two different concepts. Uniform convergence implies pointwise convergence, but not vice-versa.

Comment: Is that really the correct pointwise limit?

Comment: Thanks! I kept thinking it was $ x^{n} $.

Answer (score 3):

@sizz : It does look as if you don't know the difference between pointwise convergence and uniform convergence.

If for every $x\in\mathbb R$, $\lim_{n\to\infty} f_n(x)=f(x)$, that is **pointwise** convergence of $f_n$ to $f$.  That's what you've got here (although in order for the statement to be true just as you've stated it, you ought to have $\sqrt[n]{|x|}$).

Now look at the supremum over all $x\in\mathbb R$ of the distance between $f_n(x)$ and $f(x)$.  If that goes to $0$ as $n\to\infty$, then that is **uniform** convergence of $f_n$ to $f$.  That doesn't happen here.  You have
$$
f(x) = \begin{cases} 1 & \text{if }x\ne 0, \\ 0 & \text{if }x=0 \end{cases}
$$
and $f_n(x)=\sqrt[n]{|x|}$.  As $x\to0$, you have the distance between $f_n(x)$ and $f(x)$ approaching $1$.  So the "uniform distance" between $f_n$ and $f$ is $1$.  And that doesn't go to $0$ as $n\to\infty$.  So you don't have uniform convergence.